# Syntaxis de la media queries

Tags: css3

Una consulta en mi proyecto estoy incluyendo medias queries para 4 tipos de pantallas y quisiera saber si en el media querie puedo ponerle el max-width y el min-width ej:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-width:600px){}
```

o si simplemente ya con el max-width:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){}
```

consulto esto ya que no soy experto en esto de responsive design y quiero aprender para mejorar personalmente en este aspecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí es posible usar dos reglas al mismo tiempo, pero todo va a depender de lo que necesites. En la mayoría de los casos y desde mi experiencia, cuando hay multiples media queries no es necesario establecer adicionalmente un `min-width` por que ya hay otra query que lo establece, un ejemplo sería:

```
// Dispositivos pequeños desde 0px a 768px
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Dispositivos medianos desde 768px a 992px
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Dispositivos grandes desde 992px a 1200px
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }
```

Pero si necesitas darle soporte a un rango de pantallas muy específico, podrías usar la combinación de `max-width` y `min-width`.